# How to remove the outermost XML element tags pair, using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, string, tags

If I have a string of:

```
 <p> Abcdefg <note> abcdefg <p> abcdefg </p> <p> abcdefg </p> </note> </p>
```

I want to remove the outermost pair, in this case the first <p> and the last </p>, from the string in Javascript such that the result will be a string of:

```
 Abcdefg <note> abcdefg <p> abcdefg </p> <p> abcdefg </p> </note>
```

How would I do that? I have tried with Regex and Jquery  but I cannot do it in such a way that other inner <p> and </p> don't get removed.

Thank you.

Comment: `<p><div></div></p>` is not valid HTML. On valid HTML, you can use `$(str).html()`

Comment: @User863 Thanks, let me edit that.

Comment: @User863 The problem with that is that it removes all the inner <p> tags as well for which I dont want. I only want to remove the outer <p></p> tags.

The result of your piece is: Abcdefg <note> abcdefg </note>

Answer (score 2):

Only Phrasing contents are valid inside `p` tag.

[Available Phrasing contents](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content)

Let's consider having valid html

```js
var str = ' <p> Abcdefg <span> abcdefg <span> abcdefg </span> <span> abcdefg </span> </span> </p>'

var res = $(str).html()

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Using regex

```js
var str = '<p> Abcdefg <note> abcdefg <p> abcdefg </p> <p> abcdefg </p> </note> </p>'

var res = str.replace(/\<(.*?)\>(.*)\<\/(\1)\>/g, '$2')

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/jSAh0O/1):

```js
const regex = /<(?<tag>\w+)>(?<content>.*)<\/\k<tag>>/;

const str = '<p> Abcdefg <note> abcdefg <p> abcdefg </p> <p> abcdefg </p> </note> </p>';

const result = str.replace(regex, '$2');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function remove_tag(text, tag) {
  const regex = new RegExp(`^<${tag}>|</${tag}>$`, 'g');
  return text.replace(regex, "").trim();
}

let text = "<p> Abcdefg <note> abcdefg <p> abcdefg </p> <p> abcdefg </p> </note> </p>";
const result = remove_tag(text, "p");
console.log(result);
```